# Detect if TextBox control's text has changed without the event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know that there is an event handler `TextChanged` that fires when a TextBox control's text has been changed but I am wondering if there is another way to detect if a TextBox has had it's value changed?

I read that you can do something like store the initial value of the TextBox in the html tag but there was no detail on how to do that. Then apparently you can compare the initial value of the TextBox to it's current value and then run some code.

Comment: And why dont you wanna use `TextChanged`

Comment: we are not magicians

Comment: hahahahahaha ok sorry. Well I am having trouble with the event handler and I saw there might be a way to circumvent the problem. I have a bunch of textboxes in a nested repeater and it I want to get their values only if they have changed in a loop.

Comment: Comparing the current value to the initial value, as you described, should work just fine as well.

Comment: Is client-side an option? Or do you *need* to have the event in the server-side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a trick. You must use the native event.

```
var previousText = "";
setInterval(function(){

    var currentText = GetTextboxValue();

    if(currentText != previousText){

        // Raise the event here using currentText.

        previousText = currentText;
    }

}, 200);
```